# CodeIgniter - Store Value from Input Fields Dynamically Added in Form to MySQL Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have a case I'd like to be solved. I've been learning CI Framework for almost a month now. and what I want to do is I want to store value from input fields in a form that I add dynamically into MySQL table but I have no idea how to do that. 
I already have the script in HTML + JavaScript for the view.

**HTML script**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Account Title">
    <input type="text" name="mytext2[]" placeholder="Description">
    <input type="text" name="mytext3[]" placeholder="Credit">
    <input type="text" name="mytext4[]" placeholder="Debit">
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Account Title"><input type="text" name="mytext2[]" placeholder="Description"><input type="text" name="mytext3[]" placeholder="Credit"><input type="text" name="mytext4[]" placeholder="Debit"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

is there anyone can help me to pass the value into database from controller? sorry I'm new to CI Framework so please forgive me by asking this kind of question.

Comment: Just submit the form to the controller.  Once you have the data and you have no idea how much data is being submitted then I would most likely serialize 'serialize()' the array an insert it into the database.  When you pull it back out to use it just unserialize 'unserialize()' the string and process as normal.

Comment: thanks for answering @Blinkydamo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<form method="POST" id="myform">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="field[]" placeholder="Account Title">
    <input type="text" name="field[]" placeholder="Description">
    <input type="text" name="field[]" placeholder="Credit">
    <input type="text" name="field[]" placeholder="Debit">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This will create a form and get data as serializeArray() with jquery then pass that data to the controller with ajax or form submit

In your controller,

```
$input_data=$this->input->post();
//now input data has an array "field"  You can use that data,
you will see result array like Array ( [field] => Array ( [0] => fsdf [1] => dsfdsf [2] => dsf [3] => dsfds ) )
//$this->db->insert("target_table",$input_data);//this will insert a record into target_table in database
```

Comment: so I just have to use post() without having to do loop process to save all the data?

Comment: because I want to be able to add new input type dynamically and store that newly added input field to database as well.

Comment: Yes,$this->input->post() will get all post data into an array

Comment: then it depends on your db table structure

Comment: even with that newly added input field?

Comment: I limit the input field to only store 3 times in database.so there will be 3 emails I want to get saved. (just like Google Contacts form if you have seen it before)

Comment: is that possible to only use $this->input->post()?

Comment: then add dynamically input fileds with same name as mytext[] for all dynamically added fileds,then in post data it will receive like array

Comment: can you show me the code of it? sorry I'm newbie to CI. :(

Comment: so I just have to use the $this->input->post()? how to separate the data based on its value and store them into database if its all the same name field[]?

Comment: OMG, if you need multiple data with the same name, then use the same name for all, if you need different data then place different input types with different names

Comment: @Indra if you are not getting the answer what you need, first explain your problem briefly.